# Interceptor in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, interceptor, koa

I have tried to build a interceptor in node js, but so far I didn't get it. I want to  the interceptor, to catch every request and add a custom header, recovered from koa context.

What I mean, for example if you do http request with request-promise, I want to add automatically a custom header and propagate it to the destiny.

Anybody knows?

Answer (score 2):

Interceptors are basically middlewares.

```
// before all
app.use(function *(next) {
  this.set('x-new-header', 'value');
  yield next;
});

// the rest
app.use(routes());
```

If your Koa app is acting like a reverse-proxy. You can use the `pipe` API to propagate the new header to the remote server.

```
// before all
app.use(function *(next) {
  this.set('x-new-header', 'value');
  yield next;
});

// the reverse-proxy
const request = require('co-request');
app.use(function *() {
  this.body = this.req.pipe(request(config));
});
```